# Preventing Diabetes by preventing stress?

Tags: pathology

I have came to know that taking a lot of stress increases the risk of Diabetes, and patients of Diabetes are adviced not to take too much stress, am i correct? if yes then I am unable to understand that how stress affects the level of glucose in our blood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolonged stress leads to elevated levels of [cortisol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortisol). Cortisol interacts with insulin action and blood glucose levels in various ways, essentially promoting hyperglycaemia.